# datefield onchange handler, clientside only

Tags: tapestry

I'm using tapestry 5.3.3 (which includes the patch for issue #1844)...

Is there a simple way to catch and handle the 'onchange' event, ie where the user selects a new date (via the popup)?

I've tried:

```
<t:datefield value="dateValue" onchange="alert('here');" />
```

Thanks, Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I have to combine a both approaches to achieve what I need - whether or not this should be improved within the tapestry framework is up for debate....

```
<t:datefield t:id="selectedDateElem" id="selectedDateElem" onchange="alert('1 onchange attribute');" />

    $("selectedDateElem").observe("change", function(event)
        {
            alert("2 change observer");
        });

    document.observe(Tapestry.FOCUS_CHANGE_EVENT, function(event)
        {
            if (Tapestry.currentFocusField && Tapestry.currentFocusField.id == "selectedDateElem")
                alert("3 focus change observer");
        });
```

Test Case 1:

- User clicks into input field
- user alters value of input field
- user clicks out of input field
- --> "1 onchange attribute" & "2 change observer"

Test case 2:

- User clicks datepicker icon
- user selects a new date from popup
- --> "3 focus change observer"

So the onchange attribute is equivalent to the change observer, therefore the only complete solution is to combine approaches 2 & 3:

```
     $("selectedDateElem").observe("change", function(event)
        {
            Page.dateFieldChanged();
        });

    document.observe(Tapestry.FOCUS_CHANGE_EVENT, function(event)
        {
            if (Tapestry.currentFocusField && Tapestry.currentFocusField.id == "selectedDateElem")
                Page.dateFieldChanged();
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can catch the change event on the input field. If you are using prototype try this:

```
$('dateFieldId').observe('change', function(){
    alert('gotcha!');
    ...do whatever you will ...
});
```

I find the best way to add this js to your page is by using a seperate js file added to your page/component which you contribute to your page/componet using the [@Import](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/annotations/Import.html) annotation:

```
Tapestry.Initializer.FieldChangeObserver = function (parameters) {
    new FieldChangeObserver (parameters);
};

var FieldChangeObserver  = { };
FieldChangeObserver  = Class.create({
    initialize:function(parameters) {
    $(parameters.dateFieldId).observe('change', function(){
            alert('gotcha!');
            ...do whatever you will ...
        });
    }
});
```

Then in your page/component you can:

```
@Inject
private JavaScriptSupport javaScriptSupport;

@Component
private DateField dateField;

@AfterRender
private void afterRender() {
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject()
    params.put("dateFieldId", dateField.getCLientId());
    javaScriptSupport.addInitializerCall("FieldChangeObserver", params);
}
```

*disclaimer*: I quickly wrote this up and did not test the code.

Comment: this works for normal textfields or when typing in the datefield and then clicking out (blurring) however this is not fired when an item in the popup calendar is clicked.

Comment: http://webfx.eae.net/dhtml/datepicker/datepicker.html described how you can add a custom onchange event to the underlying webfx object. Otherwise I'm pretty sure listening to the Tapestry.FOCUS_CHANGE_EVENT might do the trick. Personally I don't use this component so I'm not sure.